# What are the differences between if, else, and else if?

Tags: c

I am trying to discern the difference between

```
if 
else 
else if
```

When do you use them and when not?

I have a homework assignment with a ton of instances and I am running into code error due to not knowing the differences between each.

Can someone please define how to use these?

Comment: You might also want to look up how to use a "case" statement as that is the other main conditional component in C and is worth contrasting to the if/else if/ else structure.

Comment: Use them (they compromise the fundamental branch structure in most programming languages) -- then you will see what they do, how they work, and what they are useful for.

Comment: `else` is equivalent to `else if (True)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
**IF** you are confused
 read the c# spec
**ELSE IF** you are kind of confused
 read some books
**ELSE**
 everything should be OK.
```

:)

Answer (score 66):

An `if` statement follows this sort of structure:

```
if (condition)
{
    // executed only if "condition" is true
}
else if (other condition)
{
    // executed only if "condition" was false and "other condition" is true
}
else
{
    // executed only if both "condition" and "other condition" were false
}
```

The `if` portion is the only block that is absolutely mandatory. `else if` allows you to say "ok, if the previous condition was not true, then if this condition is true...". The else says "if none of the conditions above were true..."

You can have multiple `else if` blocks, but only one `if` block and only one (or zero) `else` blocks.

Comment: Just to be clear for the OP: one and only one of the statement blocks will be executed during a pass through a group of if/else statements. So if both `condition` and `other condition` are true, only condition's code will be executed.

Comment: ah so if you have multiple choices inside an if, then you use the else if?

Comment: @unknown (by the way, you should register) That's correct. There are other flow control statements like "case" that can also be used for scenarios like this. Picking the right one is something you'll learn.

Comment: lol yes i should. yes we'll be working with cases next week (which looks to be an easier method than if/else?)

Comment: FYI: There's really no such thing as an "else if". It's just an else statement which contains an if statement.

Comment: @pod: semantically you're correct, but it's still an important idea to learn about.

Comment: @Pod: I agree with you.  I think it goes a long way towards clearing up confusion about how they work to realize that "else if" is a compound structure, not its own thing.  Though Adam is right that they are used as a single unit so much they are usually though of as a unit.

Answer (score 35):

If-elseif-else can be written as a nested if-else.  These are (logically speaking) equivalent:

```
if (A) 
{
    doA();
}
else if (B)
{
    doB();
}
else if (C)
{
    doC();
}
else
{
    doX();
}
```

is the same as:

```
if (A) 
{
    doA();
}
else
{
    if (B)
    {
        doB();
    }
    else
    {
         if (C)
         {
             doC();
         }
         else
         {
             doX();
         }
    }
}
```

The result is that ultimately only *one* of `doA`, `doB`, `doC`, or `doX` will be evaluated.

Comment: I'm glad someone pointed out `else if` isn't a keyword, and just a formatted combination of `else` and `if`

Comment: Agreed GMan, this isn't Python, Perl, VB etc. There's only if and else here.

Answer (score 15):

If, else and else if are all constructs to help 'branch' code.  Basically, you employ them whenever you want to make a decision.

An example would be 'if it's sunny, I'll go outside.  otherwise, I'll stay inside'

In code (ignoring the extra stuff)

```
if (sunny) {
  goOutside();
}
else {
  stayInside();
}
```

You CAN use 'else if' statements if you want to add 'additional' conditions.  Extending the previous example, "if it's sunny, I'll go outside.  If it's stormy, I'll go into the basement otherwise I'll stay inside"

In code

```
if (sunny) {
  goOutside();
}
else if (stormy) {
  goDownstairs();
}
else {
  stayInside();
}
```

EDIT section:

Here is how you can write multiple ifs as and conditions.  The following example can be written in at least two ways:

'If it's sunny and warm, go outside.  If it's sunny and cold, do nothing'

```
if (sunny) {
   if (warm) {
     goOutside();
   }
   else if (cold) {
     doNothing();
   }
}
```

OR

```
if (sunny && warm) {
   goOutside();
}
else if (sunny && cold) {
   doNothing();
}
```

Comment: +1 for using real-world concepts rather than just placeholders like `condition` or `a`, `b`, etc.

Comment: +1 for real-world concepts. How would you define the following, as this is where I am running into issues:

if it's sunny go outside. if it's sunny go to park. if it's sunny go to the store. if it's sunny go to the discoteck.

if it's stormy go downstairs. if it's stormy go in the living room. if it's stormy go into the parlor. if it's stormy go into your bedroom.

Comment: the multiple ifs inside the main if is where i am having trouble

Comment: Ifs within ifs can be rewritten using 'ands'

For example, if you want to write 'if it's sunny and warm, go outside' and 'if it's sunny and cold, do nothing' you can write it either as:

if (sunny) {
   if (warm) {
     goOutside();
   }
   else if (cold) {
     doNothing();
   }
}

OR

if (sunny && warm) {
   goOutside();
}
else if (sunny && cold) {
   doNothing();
}

I'll edit and add these examples in.

Comment: that most definitely didn't format properly.  please see the answer's edit section instead :P

Answer (score 9):

There's no "`else if`". You have the following:

```
if (condition)
    statement or block
```

Or:

```
if (condition)
    statement or block
else
    statement or block
```

In the first case, the statement or block is executed if the condition is true (different than 0). In the second case, if the condition is true, the first statement or block is executed, otherwise the second statement or block is executed.

So, when you write "`else if`", that's an "`else statement`", where the second statement is an `if` statement. You might have problems if you try to do this:

```
if (condition)
    if (condition)
        statement or block
else
    statement or block
```

The problem here being you want the "`else`" to refer to the first "`if`", but you are actually referring to the second one. You fix this by doing:

```
if (condition)
{
    if (condition)
        statement or block
} else
    statement or block
```

Comment: It is precisely this problem, known as the "dangling ELSE" problem and first seen in PASCAL (or possibly ALGOL), long before C was developed, that caused Jean Ichbiah and his team to adopt the fully-bracketed style for control structures in Ada.

Comment: +1 For there is no "else if" statement. There's an `if` statement comprised of a statement when true and [optionally] a statement when false. The developer can take advantage of the statement when false to check a new condition, and since this is an ubiquitous case it's become known as simply the "else if".

Answer (score 5):

Dead Simple Pseudo-Code Explanation:

```
/* If Example */
if(condition_is_true){
   do_this
}
now_do_this_regardless_of_whether_condition_was_true_or_false

/*  If-Else Example  */
if(condition_is_true){
    do_this
}else{
    do_this_if_condition_was_false
}
now_do_this_regardless_of_whether_condition_was_true_or_false

/* If-ElseIf-Else Example */
if(condition_is_true){
    do_this
}else if(different_condition_is_true){
    do_this_only_if_first_condition_was_false_and_different_condition_was_true
}else{
    do_this_only_if_neither_condition_was_true
}
now_do_this_regardless_of_whether_condition_was_true_or_false
```

Comment: what if you have additional conditions inside the 
<code>else if(different_condition_is_true){
    do_this_only_if_first_condition_was_false_and_different_condition_was_true
}</code>

I need to allow?

Comment: do_this_only_if_first_condition_was_false_and_different_condition_was_true could be replaced with whatever you want, if replaced with a nested if(condition){do_this} it will behave accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I think it helps to think of the "else" as the word OTHERWISE.

so you would read it like this:

```
if (something is true)
{
   // do stuff
}
otherwise if (some other thing is true)
{
   // do some stuff
}
otherwise
{
   // do some other stuff :)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (condition)
{
  thingsToDo()..
} 
else if (condition2)
{
  thingsToDoInTheSecondCase()..
}
else
{
  thingsToDoInOtherCase()..
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can think of the `if` and `else` as a pair, that satisfies `two actions` for `one given condition`.

 ex: `if` it rains, take an umbrella `else` go without an umbrella.

 there are two actions

- go with an umbrella
- go without an umbrella

and both the two actions are bound to one condition, `i.e` `is it raining?`

now, consider a scenario where there are multiple conditions and actions, bound together.

 ex: `if` you are hungry `and` you are not broke, enjoy your meal at kfc, `else if` you are hungry `but` you are broke, try to compromise, `else if` you are not hungry, but you just want to hangout in a cafe, try startbucks, `else` do anything, just don't ask me about hunger or food. i have got bigger things to worry.

 the `else if` statement to to string together all the actions that falls in between the `if` and the `else` conditions.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (numOptions == 1)
    return "if";
else if (numOptions > 2)
    return "else if";
else 
    return "else";
```

Comment: I think you meant `numOptions == 1`

Answer (score 2):

They mean exactly what they mean in English.

**IF** a condition is true, do something, **ELSE** (otherwise) IF another condition is true, do something, **ELSE** do this when all else fails.

Note that there is no *else if* construct specifically, just *if* and *else*, but the syntax allows you to place else and if together, and the convention is not to nest them deeper when you do. For example:

```
if( x )
{
    ...
}
else if( y )
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Is syntactically identical to:

```
if( x )
{
    ...
}
else 
{
    if( y )
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The syntax in both cases is:

```
if *<statment|statment-block>* else *<statment|statment-block>*
```

and *if* is itself a statment, so that syntax alone supports the use of *else if*

Answer (score 1):

The `else if` can be used in conjunction with 'if', and 'else' to further break down the logic

```
//if less than zero
if( myInt < 0){
      //do something
}else if( myInt > 0 && myInt < 10){
//else if between 0 and 10      
      //do something
}else{
//else all others  
      //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of if statement is

```
if(condition)
    something; // executed, when condition is true
else
    otherthing; // otherwise this part is executed
```

So, basically, `else` is a part of `if` construct (*something* and *otherthing* are often compound statements enclosed in `{}` and `else` part is, in fact, optional). And `else if` is a combination of two `if`s, where *otherthing* is an `if` itself.

```
if(condition1)
    something;
else if(condition2)
    otherthing;
else
    totallydifferenthing;
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are the basic decision orders that you have in most of the programming language; it helps you to decide the flow of actions that your program is gonna do.
The **if** is telling the compiler that you have a question, and the question is the condition between parenthesis

```
if (condition) {
    thingsToDo()..
}
```

the **else** part is an addition to this structure to tell the compiler what to do if the condition is false

```
if (condition) {
    thingsToDo()..
} else {
    thingsToDoInOtherCase()..
}
```

you can combine those to form a **else if** which is when the first condition is false but you want to do another question before to decide what to do.

```
if (condition) {
    thingsToDo()..
} else if (condition2) {
    thingsToDoInTheSecondCase()..
}else {
    thingsToDoInOtherCase()..
}
```

Comment: in the last ex are u missing a } to close out the else if?

Answer (score 1):

The if statement uses the results of a logical expression to decide if one of two code blocks will be executed.

With this code

```
if (logical expression) {
    code block 1;
} else {
    code block 2;
}
```

if the logical expression is true, only the statements in code block 1 will be executed; if false, only the statements in code block 2.

In the case that there are multiple similar tests to be done (for instance if we are testing a number to be less than zero, equal to zero or more than zero) then the second test can be placed as the first statement of the else code block.

```
if (logical expression 1) {
    code block 1;
} else {
    if (logical expression 2) {
        code block 2;
    } else {
        code block 3;
    }
}
```

In this case, code block 1 is executed if logical expression 1 is true;  code block 2 if logical expression 1 is false and logical expression 2 is true; code block 3 if both logical expressions are false.

Obviously this can be repeated with another if statement as the first statement of code block 3.

The else if statement is simply a reformatted version of this code.

```
if (logical expression 1) {
    code block 1;
} else if (logical expression 2) {
    code block 2;
} else {
    code block 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If and else if both are used to test the conditions.

I take case of If and else..

In the if case compiler check all cases Wether it is true or false.
if no one block execute then else part will be executed.

in the case of else if compiler stop the flow of program when it got false value.  it does not read whole program.So better performance we use else if.

But both have their importance according to situation

i take example of foor ordering menu
if i use else if then it will suit well 
because user can check only one also.
and it will give  error 
so i use if here..

```
 StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();  
            result.append("Selected Items:");  
            if(pizza.isChecked()){  
                result.append("\nPizza 100Rs");  
                totalamount+=100;  
            }  
            if(coffe.isChecked()){  
                result.append("\nCoffe 50Rs");  
                totalamount+=50;  
            }  
            if(burger.isChecked()){  
                result.append("\nBurger 120Rs");  
                totalamount+=120;  
            }  
            result.append("\nTotal: "+totalamount+"Rs");  
            //Displaying the message on the toast  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        }  

now else if case

if (time < 12) {
    greeting = "Good morning";
} else if (time < 22) {
    greeting = "Good day";
} else {
    greeting = "Good evening";
}
```

here only satisfy one condition..
and in case of if multiple conditions can be satisfied...

Answer (score 0):

**What the `if` says:**

> Whether I'm true or not, always check other conditions too.

**What the `else if` says:**

> **Only** check other conditions if i wasn't true.