# C# difference between else if and if

Tags: c#-4.0

What is the difference between if and else if in C#? For example if i write

```
if (x==5){
    do something
}
```

And

```
else if (x==5){
    do something
}
```

Are they totally same… so ? What is the difference?

Comment: You can only use `else` after an initial `if`. `else if(condition)` is basically a new check if the preceding `if` check fails. You should read up on basic c# control operators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between if, else, and else if?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439907/what-are-the-differences-between-if-else-and-else-if)

Comment: You are not going to learn a programming language by asking questions on stackoverflow.  First read beginners' books to learn the basic syntax of the language, then come to stackoverflow if you encounter a problem which is not covered by the books for beginners.

Answer (score 3):

```
**IF** you are confused
 read the c# spec
**ELSE IF** you are kind of confused
 read some books
**ELSE**
 everything should be OK.
```

Courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445365/5352399

Jokes are apart, usually an `if` statement follows this sort of structure:

```
if (condition)
{
    // executed only if "condition" is true
}
else if (other condition)
{
    // executed only if "condition" was false and "other condition" is true
}
else
{
    // executed only if both "condition" and "other condition" were false
}
```

The `if` portion is the only block that is absolutely mandatory. `else if` allows you to say "ok, if the previous condition was not true, then if this condition is true...". The else says "if none of the conditions above were true..."

You can have multiple `else if` blocks, but only one `if` block and only one (or zero) `else` blocks.

Answer reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1439915/5352399

Please read about [C# control statements](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson03) that will give you comprehensive idea.

Comment: So basically else if(){} is the same as else{if(){}} right? And everytime i write else if it is like i write else{if(){}}

Answer (score 1):

They aren't the same.

```
if (true)
 DoSomething();

if (true)
 DoSomething();
```

Versus

```
if (true)
  DoSomething();
else if (true)
  DoSomething();
```

The first example does something twice; the second does something only once.

Use else when you don't want multiple cases to be hit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky, if you use plugins like resharper and you try to write a if sentence preceding of else if sentences, resharper will tell you that the 'else' in 'else if' sentence is redundant and will refactor your code to only if sentences.

Performance issue? or we really don't know how is working c# at this days?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking is there a difference between these two:

```
if(condition0)
{
//do something
}
else if(condition1)
{
//do anything
}

//and this:
if(condition0)
{
//do something
}
else 
{
if(condition1)
{
//do anything
}
}
```