# Creating a shipping and discount calculator getting wrong numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that prompts the user to enter the number of shirts he is buying and depending on his order will determine the discount applied and the cost of shipping. I tried two different methods as seen in the fist `if` statement and then the rest. When I test it with 1 shirt I get a total of 29, for whatever reason it multiples by 29 not by 24.5 and doesn't add the 10 or less for shipping.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the number of shirts ordered:");
        int shirts = input.nextInt();
        int cost = 0;
        float shirt = 24.95f;

        if (shirts <=2) {
            cost = (int) (shirt * cost );
        }
        if (shirts <=5)
            cost = (int) (shirts*24.95f + 8.00f);   
        {
        if (shirts <=10)
            cost = (int) (shirts*24.95f + 5.00f);   

        if (shirts >=11)
            cost = (int) (shirts*24.95f);   

        System.out.print(cost);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need some `else if` statements in there

Comment: Voting to close as trivial / not likely to help future visitors

Comment: okay ill add else if but why am i getting 29 even when i test it with 1 shirt?

Comment: Run the code with your debugger and see what is happening. You really should do this if only to learn how to use your IDE's debugger.

Comment: You should also indent your code properly, to understand its structure. The IDe can do that for you, with a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: not getting any errors or anything. im not sure what im missing but i do not see how its even possible for me to get 29 as a result.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439907/what-are-the-differences-between-if-else-and-else-if)

Comment: We're not talking compiler errors but *logic* errors. Again, run through a debugger to see what your code is doing each step of the way.

Comment: How would you recommend applying a discount depending on how much someone orders? so lets say they order 3 or more they get 10% off etc..

Answer (score 0):

Your cost variable is int when it should be something like float and dont cast the result to int remove (int) from your code

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the input is 1, it is going to the below condition and returning the value as 29, which is expected. (int)(1*24.95f+5.00f)=29
if (shirts <=10)
        cost = (int) (shirts*24.95f + 5.00f);
This is the reason why it is always returing you 29.

Please change the conditions, try to use unique conditions like 
if (shirts=1) and so for so that correct value comes as output.

Hope this will help you. you can reach me if you have any further queries.

Thanks,
Raghava

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your program is the absence of `else-if` statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of shirts ordered:");
    int shirts = input.nextInt();
    int cost = 0;
    float shirt = 24.95f;

    if (shirts <=2) 
        cost = (int) (shirt * cost );

    else if (shirts <=5)
        cost = (int) (shirts*24.95f + 8.00f);   

    else if (shirts <=10)
        cost = (int) (shirts*24.95f + 5.00f);   

    else if (shirts >=11)
        cost = (int) (shirts*24.95f);   

    System.out.print(cost);

}
```

Another problem is the use of `Integer`, if you are using a pricing system it's better using floats or doubles, so change the variable cost to `double cost = 0;` that way you avoid casting all of those float calculations to `int`.

You could also check if the user inputs a number, he could accidentally input a `char` or `String`.

In your code, the reason you are getting 29 is that you use cost as an `Int` so:

1. If *1* is the input, then, `1 <= 2 = True` **BUT** since you don´t have `else-if` it keeps checking all the other `if` statements.
2. That way the last if that returns `True` is the third one making your cost variable be equal to `(int) (shirts*24.95f + 5.00f)`
3. `(int) (shirts*24.95f + 5.00f)` ->  `(int) (24.95f + 5.00f)` ->  `(int) (29.95f )` -> `29`