# Switch/Case and If - Better Solution for my case?

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

At the moment I need to automate an installation and configuration according to 2 variables taken from the computer name, location and sector. Each sector of each location has completely different configurations from each other.

Is there a better way than using "if" for each sector within "switch/case" for each location? (the number of sectors per location is less than the number of locations)

Thanks!

example:

```
public void install(string l, string s)
{
    
    switch (l)
    {
        case "10":
            {
                if (s == "CS" || s == "BO")
                {
                    //do stuff1
                    //do stuff2
                }
                if (s == "RR")
                {
                    //do stuff1
                    //do stuff2
                }
                if (s == "RC")
                {
                    //do stuff1
                    //do stuff2
                }
                break;
            }

        case "20":
            {
                if (s == "CS" || s == "BO")
                {
                    //do stuff1
                    //do stuff2
                }
                if (s == "RE")
                {
                    //do stuff1
                    //do stuff2
                    //do stuff3
                }
                if (s == "RC")
                {
                    //do stuff1
                    //do stuff2
                }
                break;
            }

        case "21":
            {
                if (s == "CS" || s == "BO")
                {
                    //do stuff1
                    
                }
                if (s == "RE")
                {
                    //do stuff1
                    //do stuff2
                }
                if (s == "RX")
                {
                    //do stuff1
                    //do stuff2
                }
                break;
            }
        (...)
    }
}
```

With Switch/Case and If it got too big and a bit messy, I don't know if there's a better way that I'm forgetting.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: You might want to review the tools at your disposal, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `else if`.

```
 public void install(string l, string s)
        {

            switch (l)
            {
                case "10":
                    {
                        if (s == "CS" || s == "BO")
                        {
                            // executed only if "condition" is true                                
                        }
                        else if (s == "RR")
                        {
                             // executed only if "condition" was false and "other condition" is true                               
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            // executed only if both "condition" and "other condition" were false
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Answer reference: [What are the differences between if, else, and else if?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439907/what-are-the-differences-between-if-else-and-else-if/1439915#1439915)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C# 7.0 or later, you can use switch-when to avoid using if.

```
switch (l)
{
    case @"10" when s is @"CS" or @"BO":
        
        break;
    case @"10" when s is @"RR":
        break;
    case @"10" when s is @"RC":
        break;
    
    case @"20" when s is @"CS" or @"BO":
        break;
    case @"20" when s is @"RE":
        break;
    case @"20" when s is @"RC":
        break;
        
    case @"21" when s is @"CS" or @"BO":
        break;
    case @"21" when s is @"RE":
        break;
    case @"21" when s is @"RX":
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to fall back to a dictionary approach for these situations.

The code is a lot more terse.

```
var stuff = new Dictionary<(string l, string s), Action>()
{
    { ("10", "CS"), () => { Stuff1(); Stuff2(); } },
    { ("10", "BO"), () => { Stuff1(); Stuff2(); } },
    { ("10", "RR"), () => { Stuff1(); Stuff2(); } },
    { ("10", "RC"), () => { Stuff1(); Stuff2(); } },
    { ("20", "CS"), () => { Stuff1(); Stuff2(); } },
    { ("20", "BO"), () => { Stuff1(); Stuff2(); } },
    { ("20", "RE"), () => { Stuff1(); Stuff2(); Stuff3(); } },
    { ("20", "RC"), () => { Stuff1(); Stuff2(); } },
    { ("21", "CS"), () => { Stuff1(); } },
    { ("21", "BO"), () => { Stuff1(); } },
    { ("21", "RE"), () => { Stuff1(); Stuff2(); } },
    { ("21", "RX"), () => { Stuff1(); Stuff2(); } },
};

if (stuff.TryGetValue((l, s), out Action action))
    action();
```

This also allows for run-time configuration which normal switches and ifs don't allow.