# Implicit declaration of elif and ; before { token in line 5

Tags: c

```cpp
#import <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            printf( "%s %s", "First parameter is ", argv[i]);
        }
        elif (i == 2) {
            printf("%s %s", "Second parameter is ", argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How is it implicit? I'm saying "else if i is 2, then print this" but they're saying it's implicit declaration. Why?

Comment: What book, tutorial or class have mentioned a statement or function like `elif` to you? There's no such thing in C. Try `else if` instead. And don't try to learn by guessing, it will only turn out badly because there are so many things that might seem to work when you try them, but actually does not work at all or work in the wrong way.

Comment: `else if` instead of `elif`. elif is python thing...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between if, else, and else if?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439907/what-are-the-differences-between-if-else-and-else-if)

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `elif`, what do you think this should mean, and **why** should it have that meaning?

Comment: BTW don't user `#import` (it's some non standard or decprecated thing). use `#include`

Answer (score 2):

There is no `elif` keyword in C.

In C, `elif (i == 2)` parses as a call of the `elif` function with a Boolean argument. As you have not declared the `elif` function, you get an 'implicit declaration' error rather than a 'this is C not Python' error.

Use `else if` instead